# getting error on compiling small C++ program

Tags: c++

when i compile the program i get an error about int when i create a bookClass object using the 2 argument constructor. the error has somerthing to do with the integer argument parsed to the constructor. the program is:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;

  class bookClass{
  private:
  string bookName;
  int bookNumber;



  public:


     void setName(string c){
    bookName=c;
    }

    void setNumber(int d){
    bookNumber=d;
    }

    string getName(){
    return bookName;
    }

    int getNumber(){
    return bookNumber;
    }
   bookClass(string a, int b){
    bookName=a;
   bookNumber=b;
    }


   };

  int main()
  {
   int numberr;
   string name;
    cout << "Enter the book name:   ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "\nEnter the book number:  ";
    cin >> numberr;

    bookClass book=new bookClass(name, numberr);

     cout << "\n\nThe book " << book.getName() << " has book number " <<        
      book.getNumber() << endl;


    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I'm sure the compiler doesn't say *"an error about int"*. Please include the actual text of the error message in your question.

Comment: You need to post the *actual error message*, not a vague recollection of what it might have been.

Comment: Consider reading the error message. Then reduce your code to a mcve. If you haven't solved the problem by then, post the mcve and the error message here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling your code I didn't get the error you suggested. However, there is an issue with this line:

```
bookClass book = new bookClass(name, numberr);
```

C++ is not Java. `new` returns a pointer to memory dynamically allocated for the given class.

What you want is just:

```
bookClass book (name, numberr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is simple. I suppose you were programming in Java or C# before C++. In C++ we call `new` operator only if we want to create an object explicitely on heap (and get a pointer to it).

```
bookClass* book=new bookClass(name, numberr);
```

However, now you are in troubles because you are calling `book.getName()` where `book` is of type pointer to something and it has no member `getName()`. You have to first dereference that pointer and then call a member function  `(*book).getName();` or simply `book->getName();`.

However, since C++'s objects do not have to be on the heap (Java objects have to) you can create an object without `new` operator using `bookClass book(name, numberr);`